# Resize Dialog Fragment like browser approach

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image]
[image]

Hi

my problem is that I want to resize my fragment with I slide up/down my fragment and I succeeded on it but the problem is the content on that fragment won't resize so my question is how can I resize also the content inside fragment or is it also possible?

my code looks like this

```
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int minWidth = (int)((double)main_container.getWidth() * .33);
        int maxHeight = main_container.getHeight();
        float container_ratio = (float)main_container.getHeight() / (float)main_container.getWidth();

        int height = (int)event.getY();
        int width = (int)(event.getY() / container_ratio);

        if (width < minWidth || height > maxHeight) {
            return true;
        }

        if (prevTouchEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && oldY != event.getY() && oldY != -1) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)fragment_broadcast.getLayoutParams();
//                layout.setMargins(0, 0, (int)ScreenUtils.dipToPixel(MainActivity.this, 10), 0);

            layout.height = height;
            layout.width = width;
            fragment_broadcast.setLayoutParams(layout);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement an [`View.OnLayoutChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html) interface on your fragment's layout, or override [`onSizeChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).  Then make what ever changes the fragment needs in terms of resizing there.